# What's Wrong with this Quartz Configuration?

Tags: java, transactions, quartz-scheduler, weblogic12c

I have Quartz Scheduler running within WebLogic 12.1.3 and backed by a JobStoreCMT, but its behavior doesn't match the configuration (see below). What am I doing wrong?

### Background

Quartz has jobs that are loaded from an XML file on startup and run periodically. Some of those jobs spawn one-time jobs. Also, there are one-time jobs that are manually triggered by users. The user-initiated jobs are done from EJBs that have container-managed transactions.

### Questions

1. The transactions in the job classes are not active in the job's execute() method. I have to call begin/commit/rollback. Shouldn't that be taken care of since *wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction* is set to true? That's what the documentation says.
2. The documentation also says that when using *XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin* with *JobStoreCMT*, *org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction* must be set to true. However, when I do that I get a duplicate transaction exception. What's going on?
3. WebLogic takes forever to shut down whenever Quartz is enabled even though all of the jobs run quickly. From the logs it looks like WebLogic is waiting for the transactions to time out. Is something in the config contributing to this?

### Configuration

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=MyTaskScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer=true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction=true
org.quartz.scheduler.userTransactionURL=javax.transaction.UserTransaction
org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime=30000
org.quartz.scheduler.dbFailureRetryInterval=15000
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=1
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow=0
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=false

org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons=false

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.weblogic.WebLogicOracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=MyDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource=MyDataSourceNonXA
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=15000
org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime=20
org.quartz.jobStore.txIsolationLevelSerializable=false
org.quartz.jobStore.txIsolationLevelReadCommitted=false 

org.quartz.dataSource.MyDataSource.jndiURL=MyDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.MyDataSource.java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
org.quartz.dataSource.MyDataSource.java.naming.provider.url=t3://localhost:7003

org.quartz.dataSource.MyDataSourceNonXA.jndiURL=MyDataSourceNonXA
org.quartz.dataSource.MyDataSourceNonXA.java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
org.quartz.dataSource.MyDataSourceNonXA.java.naming.provider.url=t3://localhost:7003

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class=org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames=E:/tasks.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound=true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval=0
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction=false
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you think that problem #2 (duplicate transaction exception) is being cause by the "extra" transaction that you are adding around the jobs (as described in question #1)? Have you tried it without manual wrapping transaction wrapping and the plugin setting set to true?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. According to the documentation the transaction in #2 should only apply to adding the job to the database. The transaction in #1 applies to taking the job from the database and running it.

Besides, the duplicate transaction error was happening before I added the "extra" transaction logic in #1.